# postgresql поиск по меткам-тегам

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Реализуем функционал -поиск по тегам. В нужных таблицах есть столбцы tags jsonb типа, где в строках этого столбца следующая структура вида:

```
{"tags":["парфюм","косметика","лаки","космос"]}
```

Запрос поиска таков:

```
select * 
from cosmetic_shop , jsonb_array_elements_text(tags->'tags') 
where value ilike 'пар%';
```

Все работает, но как нам сделать выборку не всего * , а именно самих values из массива в jsonb??? Это нужно для ajax функции при автокомплите при вводе в поисковый input. Например, человек введя символы "кос" в выпадающем suggest list увидет  "косметика" и "космос"!!

Answer (score 0):

По идеи достаточно:

```
select value 
from cosmetic_shop, jsonb_array_elements_text(tags->'tags') 
where value ilike 'пар%';
```

Comment: Не надо _так_ убирать join. В лучшем случае (pg12) будет тот же самый план, в худшем (всегда до pg12) - материализация всего списка jsonb_array_elements_text всей таблицы и лишь затем перебор всей это кучи.

Comment: Потестил на большом количестве данных, действительно просела скорость.